# Passing a variable from one query to another in same method in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to pass a variable from one query to another (bellow is the code)
If I use $data[0]->name this will give a fixed values which I need something variable like in $data[$i]->name or something.

**Controller:**

```
  public function accounts($country) {

    
    $data= DB::table("invoices")
        ->where("country", $country)
        ->select([ "name",
                    DB::raw("sum(case when type='income' then amount else 0 end) as income"),
                    DB::raw("sum(case when type='outcome' then amount else 0 end) as outcome")
                ])
        ->groupBy("name")
        ->orderBy("name", "DESC")
        ->get();


    $payments= DB::table("payments")
        ->where("name", $data[0]->name) // here is the variable I want to pass from the above $data query
        ->where("country", $country)
        ->select([  
                    DB::raw("sum(case when type='income' then amount else 0 end) as payment_income"),
                    DB::raw("sum(case when type='outcome' then amount else 0 end) as payment_outcome")
                ])
        ->groupBy("name")
        ->orderBy("name", "DESC")
        ->get();

    return view('accounting.accounts')
    ->with('accounts',$data)
    ->with('payments',$payments);

   }
```

**View:**

```
 @foreach($accounts as $account)
   @foreach($payments as $payment)
     <tr>
        <th>{{$account->name}}</th>
        <td>{{$account->income}}</td>
        <td>{{$payment->payment_income}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{$account->outcome}}</td>
        <td>{{$payment->payment_outcome}}</td>
        <td></td>
     <tr>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to get data for all $data rows in the second query?

Comment: so you want a `whereIn` becuase there will be multiple you are looking for?

Comment: I want to get the data for all rows in the second query where they match $data->name of the first query of its running time. as if it was a $data[$i]->name

Comment: @AmjadI.Bawarshi For that, I think you should use a foreach in order to iterate through all the values of $names.
And with each result, add them to a table and display it in your view afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
$names = $data->pluck('name');

$payments= DB::table("payments")
        ->where("country", $country)
        ->whereIn("name", $names) 
        ->select([  
                    DB::raw("sum(case when type='income' then amount else 0 end) as payment_income"),
                    DB::raw("sum(case when type='outcome' then amount else 0 end) as payment_outcome")
                ])
        ->groupBy("name")
        ->orderBy("name", "DESC")
        ->get();
return view('accounting.accounts')
->with('accounts',$data)
->with('payments',$payments);
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I have edit the answer where clause comes first. Also, If pluck is not working try to use foreach to get all the names in a $names array and the rest should be the same

Comment: it retrieved empty values. my table is empty in the view

Comment: after the update, your code seems to work but I get repeated values...
please see this screenshot https://pasteboard.co/JLrRJ50.png
I need it to be grouped by name so only one customer name is per row

Comment: do you get repeated values in $names?

Comment: If the answer was useful kindly, accept the answer